# How can I iterate some array and generate hash

Tags: javascript, arrays, hash

I have the following array:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I need to create a hash based on the array above like this:

```
cars = { models: [ { 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: '' } ] }
```

How can I create this hash and access some value like this:

```
cars['models]['2']
```

Comment: Do you mean like `cars  = { models: Object.fromEntries(array.map(n => [n, ''])) }`? By the way, that would be `{ models: { 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: '' } }` (note the removal of the unit array wrapping the object literal).

Comment: yes, by how can I access hash['models'][1] ? this way isn't working. thanks

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento I realize you're new to SO, but "this isn't working" isn't a good enough explanation. What is it that you've tried/what error do you get?

Comment: ok. I'm trying to access { models: { 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: 'A', 5: '' } } using: cars['models']['4'] and should return 'A'

Answer (score 0):

`cars['model']['2']` can't match the data structure you show, because 
 `models` is an Array not a javascript object.

you have to use `cars.model[0]['2']`   or `cars['model'][0]['2']`

```js
const createHash=arr=>
{
  let model = []
  model[0] = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(n => [n, 'x'])) 
  return {model}
}


let cars =  createHash ( [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] )

console.log ( cars.model[0]['2'] )
console.log ( 'cars :', JSON.stringify( cars ) )
```

If you want to match `cars['model']['2']` you have to change your data structure to `cars : {"model":{"1":"y","2":"y","3":"y","4":"y","5":"y"}}`

```js
// different structure :
const createHash=arr=>
{
  let model = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(n => [n, ''])) 
  return {model}
}


let cars =  createHash ( [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] )

cars['model']['4'] = 'A'

console.log( "cars['model']['4'] ->", cars['model']['4'])

console.log ( 'cars :', JSON.stringify( cars ) )
```

Comment: See OP's latest comment on their question - they are mentioning two different structures, might be worthwhile to sort out which model really is desired.

Comment: `cars['models]['2']` can't match his data structure.

Comment: Agreed, not the structure presented in the question.  But the structure in the comment is `{ models: { 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: 'A', 5: '' } }` - and `cars['models']['2']` would work there....

Comment: @cale_b (the comment of the OP arrived while I corrected my answer) and if I put values to x it is because the empty chains do not return anything in a file console.log. Why are you so picky?